# jquery post not calling php

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to send a variable from the browser when  a use logs into the server.
I am not able to achieve that...

php code:

```
<?php
echo "test";
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;

  echo $email;
?>
```

html page:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Demo</title>
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <script>

           alert("test");

$.post("receiver.php", { email: "John", message: "2pm" } )s;


</script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Can you please let me know what I am missing . looks I am missing some thing very basic..
echo test in the php file is also not printing

Comment: the `s` at the end of your `$.post()` call? Use your browsers console to check for javascript errors.

Comment: You won't see the echoed value because you aren't doing anything with it.  Watch the AJAX activity in your browser's console, and you should see the email in the HTTP response from the PHP script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a function that handles whatever's returned by the php (you also had a slight syntax error like @tigrang said).  Try this:

```
$.post("receiver.php", { email: "John", message: "2pm" }, function(data){ console.log(data);});
```